# simulating the winner of a game when the chance of them winning is given

Tags: r, prediction, simulation

I have this problem where there are two teams: a and b. They play a series of 5 games that are each independent of the other. The winner of each game is given a certain number of points. Whichever team has the most points at the end wins the series. Each game is played and there are no ties, either a or b wins. I am given the chances for each team to win for each game and the number of points each game is worth.

DATA

`GAME  A      B     PTS
1     33.5  65.8     1
2     76.2  23.0     2
3     46.8  53.2     3
4     12.2  75.4     4
5     65.3  8.40     5`

I am trying to simulate a winner for each game, then based on who wins add up their scores for each game to give a winner of the series. This would be simulated for 100 5-game series. The part I am not sure about is how to simulate a winner for an individual game based on their chance of winning. I found this link on stat.exchange [about simulating head to data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253515/how-to-model-a-logistic-regression-with-head-to-head-data). This post pointed to using [BradleyTerry2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/vignettes/BradleyTerry.pdf) R package. I read through the article and example 3.3 looks similar to what I am trying to do though I am not really sure how to implement it or how it predicts a winner. If this is not the approach to take I am open for pointers.

Here is my code so far

```
    install.packages("BradleyTerry2")
    library("BradleyTerry2")

    a <- c(33.5,76.2,46.8,12.2,65.3)
    b <- c(65.8,23,53.2,75.4,8.4)
    pts <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

    # simulate 100 5-game series
    for (x in 1:100)
    {
      a_pts <- 0
      b_pts <- 0

      # loop through each game to predict winner
      for (g in 1:5)
      {
        # predict winner of game
          # this is where i need help

        # give winning team pts
        if(a[g]==1)
        {
          a_pts <- a_pts + pts[g]
        }
        if(b[g]==1)
        {
          b_pts <- b_pts + pts[g]
        }
      }

      # tally up series won by a
      if(a_pts > b_pts)
      {
        a_games[x] <- 1
      }
      if(a_pts < b_pts)
      {
        a_games[x] <- 0
      }
    }

    # probability of a winning series
    sum(a_games==1)/100
```

At this point I am just trying to figure out how to simulate the winner of an individual game based on their chance of winning. I will fix the checks to add points to the winner based on code/variables for predicting a winner. I am fairly new to both stats and R so any suggestions for generating a simulation either in R (preferable) or using statics equations I am open to hear.

Comment: Are the probabilities of each team winning given in column A and column B? If so, and the columns represent percentages, shouldn't the sum of column A and column B for each game be 100 given there are no ties?

Comment: Do these teams cross paths in game number 3?

Comment: @Wes yes columns a and b are the probabilities each team winning. I agree with you that they should equal a 100. Technically there was a third team which accounts for the missing percent, but through the course of the problem that was given me the third team was dropped and it was only looking at 2 teams. If it makes creating a simulation easier then the percent total for A and B can be made to equal a hundred. I am trying to understand how to do the simulation based on the probability of each team winning.

Comment: @AntoniParellada A and B compete against each other in each game

Comment: As perhaps an overly naive approach, you could use the rbinom() function and the probability of success for a given team? This would give you a vector indicating successes and losses for that given game... and should be OK given each game is independent.

Something along the lines of a<-rbinom(100,1,0.335) for game 1, with values of 1 indicating a win for team A. Just focusing on that as you say that is the part you are having difficulties with

Comment: @Wes thanks. Definitely was trying to make this way harder. I knew there had to be an easier way. Let me play with that and see if I can get it to work with the scoring aspect

Comment: @Wes thanks for the rbinom idea. That worked well I used that and posted my code solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code solution I came up with based on @Wes suggestion of using rbinom. I modified and cleaned up my code. This will loop through each game using rbinom to generate a 0 or 1 for N number of simulations using the probability P of winning the game. It will then loop through each game and assign the corresponding points for the games in the 5 game series if the value is 1

```
    a <- c(33.5,76.2,46.8,12.2,65.3)
    b <- c(65.8,23,53.2,75.4,8.4)
    pts <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    N <- 100
    a_pts <- rep(0,N)

    # loop through each game to predict winner
    for (g in 1:5)
    {
      # predict winner of game
      P <- a[g]/100
      a_games <- rbinom(N,1,P)

      # loop through each game and assign corresponding points
      for (x in 1:N)
      {
        if(a_games[x]==1)
        {
          a_pts[x] <- a_pts[x] + pts[g]
        }
      }
    }

    # probability of a winning series
    sum(a_pts>=8)/N
```

Comment: A word of caution, using the values a as the probability for the rbinom() function does not correspond to the probabilities defined in b (see my comment on sum of probabilities above). Defining b and b_pts is essentially redundant in this code.

Comment: @Wes I agree. thanks. I removed the line. I thought I had removed all the references to b when I had cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R but i would solve the problem like this :

While (!stop)
{
  If (Rnd ()<=a [g]/100) a wins stop=true;
  If (Rnd ()<=b [g]/100) b wins stop=true;
}

Rnd () is the random generator giving a real number between 0 and 1

However i don't understand your check for winner :

If (a [g]==1)

You should use another variable to store who won a particular game if you want to reuse the lists a [] and b []

Comment: I don't think this answer is very helpful.  I think the problem is with the lack of clarity if the question.